# Authentication with client certificates

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, client-certificates

I have a web app that uses authentication with client certificates.  I'm trying to hit a web service (URL) available in that app, but I'm confused about how to set the certificate information.

If I hit the URL directly from my browser it works fine.

Is it possible to get the client information from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Curl you can disable SSL verifyhost and verifypeer

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Or you can set a valide certificat like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt");
```

Both solution work, the first is a bit simpler

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those options is working for me because the web service requires a client cert.

Comment: Ahh so you need to create a cert, this link describe everything step by stepl: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: That link looks like the same as what was included in your original answer.  And I don't need to create a user cert, I just need to use the one configured in the browser if possible.

Comment: Nop, everything explained on this link, in the example he download the cert from a dist server 

 "In order to do this, we first need to get the CA certificate. In this example, I’ll be using the https://api.del.icio.us/ server as a reference."

Comment: I have the ca certificate.  I need the user certificate.  Sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: Once I put the .pem file in a folder that was accessible by the user that owns/runs the apache/httpd procerss, this worked great!